# Using microsoft azure eventgrid trigger output binding, how to support cloudEvent Schema 01

Tags: azure, azure-functions, python-3.10, azure-eventgrid, cloudevents

I'm using Azure event grid trigger output binding python v2 model, the trigger works fine, the events type is cloudSchema. For the output i keep getting

> message": "This resource is configured to receive event in 'CloudEventV10' schema. The JSON received does not conform to the expected schema. Token Expected: StartObject, Actual Token Received: StartArray

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import datetime

@app.function_name(name="eventgrid_output")
@app.route(route="eventgrid_output")
@app.event_grid_output(
    arg_name="outputEvent",
    topic_endpoint_uri="MyEventGridTopicUriSetting",
    topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")
def eventgrid_output(eventGridEvent: func.EventGridEvent, 
         outputEvent: func.Out[func.EventGridOutputEvent]) -> None:

    logging.log("eventGridEvent: ", eventGridEvent)

    outputEvent.set(
        func.EventGridOutputEvent(
            id="test-id",
            data={"tag1": "value1", "tag2": "value2"},
            subject="test-subject",
            event_type="test-event-1",
            event_time=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            data_version="1.0"))
```

**How do i set the output type to CloudEventV10**

Successfully publishing the event triggered the function

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
You are not using Event hub Trigger but you are using its `arg name` in the function which is `eventGridEvent: func.EventGridEvent,`, which is resulting in error

> Exception: FunctionLoadError: cannot load the test function: the following parameters are declared in Python but not in function.json: {'eventGridEvent'}

I have used EventHub Trigger and Event Hub output binding in same trigger to  get output.

For reference check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/cloudevents-schema)

##### My Code:

```py
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="eventgrid_out")
@app.event_grid_trigger(arg_name="eventGridEvent")
@app.event_grid_output(
    arg_name="outputEvent",
    topic_endpoint_uri="MyEventGridTopicUriSetting",
    topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")
def eventgrid_output(eventGridEvent: func.EventGridEvent, 
         outputEvent: func.Out[func.EventGridOutputEvent]) -> None:

    logging.info("eventGridEvent: %s", eventGridEvent)

    outputEvent.set(
        func.EventGridOutputEvent(
            id="test-id",
            data={"tag1": "value1", "tag2": "value2"},
            subject="test-subject",
            event_type="test-event-1",
            event_time=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            data_version="1.0"))
```

## `OUTPUT`:

To check the output binding data sent to  event grid, I used a service bus queue.

[image]

[image]

I think it is not mention properly in document, I have created Document correction [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/120643). follow the issue for further updates.